# Is there a fast way to append the session name to all links?

Tags: php, session, output-buffering

Is there a fast and efficient way to append a `?sid=asdasdasd` or a `&sid=asdasdasd` to all urls on a page using PHP? Should I use output buffering for this?

I'm trying to have something like:

```
<a href="/something.php">hello</a>
```

to change to:

```
<a href="/something.php?sid=somethingrandom">hello</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP configuration, turn off session cookies, and turn on [transparent sid support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid), which will automatically rewrite links to include a session ID.

Note that URL-based sessions are considered a bad practice.

Comment: In my .htaccess, I tried setting `php_flag session.use_trans_sid on` 
and `php_flag session.use_cookies 0`, but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you know if you are allowed to override these things? Is this not your own server?

Comment: If it's your own server, why are you using `php_flag` directives in a `.htaccess` file instead of editing php.ini?

Comment: Your bio is quite accurate. You *are* lazy.